# What happened to Router.go()?

Tags: meteor

Doesn't this command still exist in iron-router?  Why am I getting this error?

```
TypeError: Object function router(req, res, next) {                                                          // 13
    //XXX this assumes no other routers on the parent stack which we should probably fix      // 14
    router.dispatch(req.url, {                                                                // 15
      request: req,                                                                           // 16
      response: res                                                                           // 17
    }, next);                                                                                 // 18
  } has no method 'go'
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to wrap it in "if (Meteor.isClient)" if it's going to run at startup time.  Which is funny because you can have calls to Router.route() that aren't wrapped and they run fine.